# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log thrown with No version conflict

Tags: spring, junit, log4j, pom.xml, slf4j

I have seen other questions regarding the same error and none of the solution worked for me.
I searched through dependency hierarchy and there was **NO version conflict**.

I have a JUnit 4 test. On running the test, I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jLocationAwareLog.error(LogAdapter.java:433)
```

Following dependencies has been added in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency
```

Sping version: 5.2.6
Junit: 4

Any idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: You are using a too old version of slf4j. Use something in the 1.7 range.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added 1.7.0. Still no luck. In fact I get this error in console: `SLF4J: The requested version 1.6.99 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8]` I got this error when using version 1.5.11 also.

Comment: As per the error, I added slf4j of 1.5.8 . So this error is solved, but `LocationAwareLogger` still exists

Comment: You shouldn't upgrade only the API but both versions.

Comment: @M.Denium Yes, I upgraded both slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12

Comment: Also why is the scope provided? That should be compile to be usable.

Comment: @M.Denium Tried changing scope also. But no luck